# Farey Sequence Vector Orthogonality Relation Question

Tags: number-theory, vector-spaces, arithmetic-functions, farey-sequences

Take the [Farey sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) $\mathcal{F}_n$ for $n=39$ with values $a_m\in \mathcal{F}_n$ and put them into a vector
$$
\vec v_k=\biggr(\exp(2\pi i k a_m)\biggr)_m
$$

Since [Merten's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#As_a_sum_over_Farey_sequences) for $n=39$ is zero
$$
M(39)= \sum_{a\in \mathcal{F}_{39}} e^{2\pi i a} =0  ,
$$
our vector $\vec v_1$ is orthogonal to the vector containing only $1$'s, i.e. $\vec v_0$.
For all  $k\in OV=\{  1,  17    ,19    ,28    ,41    ,43    ,47    ,53    ,59    ,61
    ,67,...\}$
I get vectors orthogonal to $\vec v_0$.
The integer sequence $OV$ doesn't seem to be know to OEIS.
As Greg pointed out the set is periodic with period $\mathop{\rm lcm}[1,\dots,39] = 5342931457063200$.

$OV$ contains all primes larger than $39$ (denoted $p_{\gt39}$) and all products of them.

All numbers $k\pmod 2 \equiv 0$, I found$^*$ are either of the form $2^27^np_{\gt 39}$ or $2\cdot 3^27^np_{\gt39}$.

All numbers $k\pmod 5 \equiv 0$, I found$^*$ are either of the form $5\cdot 7 \cdot 11 p_{\gt 39}$ or $5\cdot 13\cdot 23p_{\gt39}$.

$17$ and $19$ complete the list of primes till $23$, leaving a gap containing  $29,31$ and $37$.

> How can the products of small primes and the gap be explained?

$^*: {\scriptstyle\text{I searched the first $122827$ roots...}}$

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer but rather a way to start propertly investigating the problem. The sum of $\exp(2\pi i k b/q)$ over all reduced fractions $b/q$ with denominator $q$ is equal to [Ramanujan's sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum) $c_q(k)$. So the quantity you're describing is
$$
\vec v_0\cdot\vec v_k = \sum_{a_m\in\mathcal F_{39}} \exp(2\pi i k a_m) = \sum_{j=1}^{39} c_j(k).
$$
For example, when $k=1$, it's known that $c_j(k) = \mu(j)$ (the Möbius mu function). And sure enough, $\sum_{j=1}^{39} \mu(j)=0$.

[A formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum#von_Sterneck) for $c_j(k)$ is known for all $j$ and $k$, so you can start looking at that. One consequence is that your set $OV$ is actually periodic: it's a union of residue classes modulo $\mathop{\rm lcm}[1,\dots,39] = 5342931457063200$.

Comment: Ok thanks so far. Let's see how Srinivasa or von Sterneck can help me...

Comment: Hey, I added some numbers to my question and would be glad if you could have a look? Thanks and good night...

Comment: It's clear from the Ramanujan sum formula that $k\in OV$ if $k$ isn't divisible by any prime less than $39$. But for numbers divisible by small primes: why do you think the "gap" needs explaining? I think it's just random-ish - the same way that it's random-ish that $\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mu(j)=0$ at $J=39$.

Comment: I think the gap could be explained. When $J=40$, $31$ is the only number I haven't yet in the factors of the elements of the corresponding $OV$ set. Since $k=31$ sends 31 elements to $1$, it looks like we can't compensate this to an overall zero...

Comment: Hey Greg, I posted a follow-up [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765090/unitary-farey-sequence-matrices) and I hope you can help me...