# Find all integer solutions of the equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions to $3^a+7=2\cdot5^b$.

Basically I've tried almost every tool I know of NT (Zsigmondy,LTE,reducing to various modulus) but nothing worked.

So far I just know that (1,1) works.

Comment: $3^5 + 7 = 2\cdot 5^3$. I suspect these are the only ones.

Comment: Maybe... any hints on how to prove it?

Comment: If I knew how to prove it, I'd have posted an answer.

Comment: I would be interested since I had a similar problem: [Solutions to $3\cdot 5 p_1 \pm 37^n p_2 =2^b\cdot 29^m p_3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/766555/19341)

Comment: To get to @DanielFischer's solution, subtract 5 from both sides and look at mod 5 (eg), and 4 from both sides and look at mod 3. His solution are the smallest positive ints satisfying what you'll see. I got there, but not further in my scribbling.

Comment: *a* and *b* are both odd. This follows from $\mod4$ and $\mod6$.

Comment: Then $3x^4+7=10y^2$, where $a=4m+1$ (from mod 5) and $b=2n+1$, and you can solve the Pellian.  That might give more information about $x$ and $y$, and why they can/cannot be powers of $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Note $5$ is a primitive root modulo powers of $3$ and vice versa, so exploiting the $(5,3)$ we get $100\mid a-5$ and $162\mid b-3$ for any non-trivial $(a,b)$. I wonder if repeating this strategy will ever give some results (I once saw a German contest problem similar to this one where that strategy eventually gave a contradiction).

Comment: @barto You were on the right track!

Answer (score 3):

$(1,1)$ and $(5,3)$ are the only solutions.

Suppose we have a solution which is larger than this. Then the RHS is divisible by $5^4 = 625$, and so the LHS must also be.

The order of $3$ modulo $625$ is $500$, and $3^{105} + 7$ is divisible by $625$. So we need: 
$$a \equiv 105 \pmod{500}$$

Now, the order of $3$ modulo $3001$ is $500$, and $\text{LHS} \equiv 3^{105} + 7 \equiv 1735 \pmod{3001}$. So for such a solution to exist, we need:

$$2\cdot 5^b \equiv 1735 \pmod{3001}$$

But the order of $5$ modulo $3001$ is $250$, and an exhaustive search of the $250$ powers of $5$ modulo $3001$ shows that this cannot happen.

So $(1,1)$ and $(5,3)$ are indeed the only solutions.

Comment: Exhaustive search of the powers of $5$ modulo $3001$ confirmed using Sage.